# Which Debian package architecture am I using?

Tags: debian, package-management, aptitude, packages

What's the command to find out which Debian package architecture I'm using?

eg, on a 64 bit x86, I'm expecting something like `amd64`, `i386` on 32 bit x86 and `darwin-x86_64` from OSX 10.6 (via Fink).

Answer (score 117, accepted):

or

`dpkg --print-architecture`

Answer (score 20):

`dpkg-architecture -qDEB_HOST_ARCH`

Comment: `dpkg-architecture` is in the `dpkg-dev` package which isn't installed by default (although it is a dependency of `build-essential`). However, `dpkg` is by definition guaranteed to be there.

Comment: @NeilMayhew good call, switched my accepted answer

Answer (score 17):

In case you did add some other architecture that you forgot, like i386 to an amd64 system, you can check it by:

```
dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
```

Source: https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO